# Ошибка 1273 Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci ' при миграции в Laravel

Tags: mysql, openserver, laravel-5.7

Всем привет! При запуске кода **php artisan migrate** в консоле появилась такая ошибка:

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1273 Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci ' (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = testlaravel and tabl
  e_name = migrations)
In MySqlConnector.php line 56:

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1273 Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci '

Answer (score 0):

У вас старая версия openserver либо в настройках openserver'а выбрана слишком старая версия mysql. Поставьте версию MySQL версии 5.5.3 или выше.

Ошибка говорит о том, что mysql не знает такой collation, она появилась начиная с 5.5.3